# DSum for textbox on Report only shows up after closing or compact/repair

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have seven textboxes on a report that are populated by DSum using VBA. The correct values will only show up after doing a compact/repair or closing the database and reopening it.

I have tried turning off Compact on Close to see if that made a difference and it didn't.

I've put refresh and requery everywhere and still no luck.

I've adjusted the control source for txtLTL so that it looks for a simple value instead of the longer query, nothing.

I've manually set the control source, nothing. The reason for doing it in VBA is so that it's easier to replicate across all of our databases.

Here's the code:

```
Me.txtUPS.ControlSource = "=DSum(""CCur(Shipping)"",""Orders"",""ShipMethod Like 'UPS%'"")"
Me.txtUSPS.ControlSource = "=DSum(""Shipping"",""Orders"",""ShipMethod Like 'USPS%'"")"
Me.txtFedEx.ControlSource = "=DSum(""Shipping"",""Orders"",""ShipMethod Like 'Fed%'"")"
Me.txtDHL.ControlSource = "=DSum(""Shipping"",""Orders"",""ShipMethod Like 'DHL%'"")"
Me.txtLTL.ControlSource = "=DSum(""Shipping"",""Orders"",""shipmethod not like 'UPS%' and shipmethod not like 'USPS%' and shipmethod not like 'fed%' and shipmethod not like 'DHL%' and shipmethod not like 'CPU' and shipmethod not like 'Courier' and shipping > 0"")"
Me.txtCourier.ControlSource = "=DSum(""Shipping"",""Orders"",""ShipMethod Like 'Courier'"")"
Me.txtCPU.ControlSource = "=DSum(""Shipping"",""Orders"",""ShipMethod Like 'CPU'"")"
```

Here's the strange thing - txtLTL will populate with everything the first time the code runs but after closing and reopening, the correct textboxes will populate.

I'm completely at a loss now.

Comment: Why do you set the ControlSources at runtime by VBA (and not in report design)? -- In which event is this code located?

Comment: Original post updated. The reason for doing it in VBA is so that it's easier to replicate across all of our databases. It's being fired from on open.

Answer (score 0):

A solution (or rather workaround) for this kind of problems can be:

Set `Form.TimerInterval` to `1`

Then add the `Form.Timer` event procedure like this:

```
Private Sub Form_Timer()
    Me.TimerInterval = 0  ' turn off timer!
    Me.Recalc  ' this should be the correct method
End Sub
```

Using `Timer` instead of `Open` or `Load` ensures that the Recalc is executed **after** the form has finished loading.